# How can I allow a client to edit certain parts of a static site?

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a website created using bootstrap and want to allow for my client to have some control and editing abilities, hence why I want to migrate it to wordpress. The client wants to be able to add new pages which must show up in the multilayer navbar. They also want to be able to edit text about the company, which appears on the home page, as well as change the images in the slider. No other parts will need to be edited by them (ie not the footer and such).

I'm unsure how to take my static, fully designed html and bootstrap site and migrate it over AND allow only certain parts of it to be changed by the client. I've looked into migrating the site onto wordpress and it seems as easy as creating a few php files and pasting code into them, but the navbar, links to pages and slider are all hard coded into the html. How can I allow for these aspects to be edited from the dashboard and not just from the code itself?

Comment: See this very similar question and answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324865/correct-way-to-make-static-pages-editable-in-wordpress/324882#324882

Answer (score -1):

in first you have to know how convert your static html pages into wordpress themes ,
then about your navbar put this code in your theme function.php

```
function register_my_menu() {  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));}add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

then go to your header.php where your navbar is and remove nav and put this code in it

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

and it will put your custom navbar from wordpress dynamic . for instructions look at [wordpress navbar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)